# SwiftUI: ObservedObject/ObservableObject weird behavior

Tags: swift, swiftui, observableobject, observedobject

I recently encountered the following problem in `SwiftUI` with `ObservedObject`/`ObservableObject`:

If the `ObservedObject`/`ObservableObject` is publishing in a View, the `body` property is recalculated - as expected.

But if there is a sub View in the `body` property which also has an `ObservedObject`, the View, strangely enough, not only recalculates the `body` property of the sub View, but the entire `object`.

**The state** of the `ObservedObject` **is** of course **lost** from the sub View.

Of course, you can prevent this by adding the `ObservableObject` to the sub View through `.environmentObject()`, but I don't think that's the best solution, especially with more complex view hierarchies.

Here an example Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var contentViewModel: ContentViewModel = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                self.contentViewModel.counter += 1
            } label: {
                Text(String(self.contentViewModel.counter))
            }
            
            SubView()
        }
    }
}
```

```
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var counter: Int = 0
}
```

And the sub View:

```
struct SubView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var subViewModel: SubViewModel = SubViewModel()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            self.subViewModel.counter += 1
        } label: {
            Text(String(self.subViewModel.counter))
        }
    }
}
```

```
class SubViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var counter: Int = 0
}
```

And here how the sample Code looks/works:

[image: Preview]

The last weird thing I realised, this is only the case if you use Observed Object. If I would replace in the sub View `@ObservedObject var subViewModel: SubViewModel = SubViewModel()` with `@State var counter: Int = 0` it is working fine again and the state is preserved.

Maybe im missing out on something, but im really confused. Im very grateful for any answers and solutions. If you have further questions fell free to leave a comment, I will answer it within 24h (as long as the question is open).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a perfect solution:

Either you replace the `@ObservedObject` with `@StateObject` (thx @Raja Kishan) in iOS 14 (SwiftUI v2.0) or you can create a Wrapper for the View and simulate the behaviour of `@StateObject` in iOS 13 (SwiftUI v1.0):

```
struct SubViewWrapper: View {
    @State var subViewModel: SubViewModel = SubViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        SubView(subViewModel: self.subViewModel)
    }
}
```

and then use `SubViewWrapper()` in ContentView instead of `SubView()`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var contentViewModel: ContentViewModel = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                self.contentViewModel.counter += 1
            } label: {
                Text(String(self.contentViewModel.counter))
            }
            
            SubViewWrapper()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Declare your ViewModel with `@StateObject`. `@StateObject` is not recreated for every view re-render [more](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject)

```
struct SubView: View {
    @StateObject var subViewModel: SubViewModel = SubViewModel() //<--- Here
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            self.subViewModel.counter += 1
        } label: {
            Text(String(self.subViewModel.counter))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you <3. Just one question, why is "ObservedObject" not working here? I would love to understand the error and where to use "ObservedObject" and where "StateObject". Also my app is currently iOS 13 :P

Comment: just read articles: https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/07/02/the-difference-between-stateobject-environmentobject-and-observedobject-in-swiftui/

Comment: Ok thanks for the link and the answer. <3

Comment: But what is the solution in iOS 13 aka SwiftUI 1?